# Execute commands in session without passing it to every one of them

Tags: c#, mongodb, transactions

In my application I use repository pattern and I want to be able to execute some methods from repository (or more repositories) in a session with transaction. 
It should be optional, so sometimes I want to add user without using a transaction, but somewhere else I want to execute the same method in session and transaction.
I dont want to create overload on every repository method with optional IClientSessionHandle parameter, that sounds very ugly to me.

I tried to basically implement Unit of Work pattern like I used in Entity Framework. Code I have but doesn't work looks like this:

```
using (var uow = _uowProvider.Create())
{
     repository.Add(someEntity);   
     repository.Add(otherEntity);
     uow.Commit(); //just calls CommitTransaction on wrapped session
}
```

The "uow" in this example just wraps IClientSessionHandle and I hoped that if I create collections from this session, they would be included in it and its transaction, but they are not.

Inside IUnitOfWorkProvider I instantiate collections (simplified) like this:

```
_unitOfWorkProvider.Current == null
                       ? collection
                       : _unitOfWorkProvider.Current.Session.Client.GetDatabase(collection.Database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName)
                           .GetCollection<T>(collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName);
```

Result is, that my commands (like InsertOneAsync etc.) are not executed in session, because I don't pass the session object to them. If I pass null session the the call (because session/transaction is optional) it throws NRE.

Is there a way to optionally execute commands on mongo collections without explicitly passing session instance to them?

Comment: Encountered the exact same problem and landed on this question. Have you found any solution to this (apart from the solution in the answer below)?

Comment: In the end I was not able to implement what I wanted using mongo driver at the time. Maybe current version handles this better and it is possible now.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the source code of [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) to see how it tackles this issue. end result is transaction code that looks like this:

```cs
    using (var TN = new Transaction())
    {
         var author1 = new Author { Name = "one" };
         var author2 = new Author { Name = "two" };

         TN.Save(author1);
         TN.Save(author2);

         TN.Commit();
         }
    }
```